# Converting columns into rows in oracle using sql only

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, pivot

How can I convert the columns as a rows of a table including the headers also in oracle.

```
slno id name
1    A  XXXX
2    B  YYYY
3    C  ZZZZ
4    D  MMMM
```

I want output like

```
     col1 col2 col3 col4
slno 1    2    3    4
id   A    B    C    D
name XXXX YYYY ZZZZ MMMM
```

Comment: maybe unpivot would help? I've always used pivot only, so I cannot really tell.

Comment: This is normally done by the client. What tool are you using to present this data?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it on ms sql, may be this should help, you can make some changes according to the oracle

```
select * from(
  select slno,id,name from [tablename]
) abc
pivot
(
  slno,id,name for [Group]
  in (col1,col2,col3)
)
as pvt
```

i was working with the adventure works 2012 database
and there i used it here

```
select * from(
  select [CountryRegionCode],[Group],[SalesYTD] from [Sales].[SalesTerritory]
) abc
pivot
(
  sum([SalesYTD]) for [Group]
  in ([North America], [Europe],[Pacific])
)
as pvt
```